# why is the output only the character 'u'

Tags: c

I am kind of new to the C language. what is happening below? the output is only "u"

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    printf("%c\n",'pasundu');
}
```

Comment: Hint: `%c` is meant for `char` whereas `'pasundu'` is not `char`

Comment: Use  `printf("%s\n","pasundu");` instead of  `printf("%c\n",'pasundu');`

Comment: You should compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...); you would get a warning. Improve the code to get no warnings, then **use the debugger**  `gdb`

Answer (score 1):

You're putting `%c` in your `printf` statement, telling the compiler that you want to print a single character.

You're also using single quotes `'` around the sequence of characters  `pasundu` - what you have here is a multicharacter literal. Multicharacter literals have an implementation-defined value - in this case it appears the compiler is taking the last character in your literal.

To fix this, I assume you want to display `pasundu` as a string:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n","pasundu");
}
```

Note that I've also changed the return type of `main`, as void is allowed but isn't required to be supported in all compilers.

Comment: Are you sure `void()` isn't standard compliant? C99 specifically says it should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: _"It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters...or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared)...or in some other implementation-defined manner. "_ So implementations can allow void but it may not be portable. I'll rephrase in my answer.

Comment: Later on it also says that `The special case of an unnamed parameter
of type void as the only item in the list specifies that the function
has no parameters.`. It's well defined by C99. It also says that `The
use of function definitions with separate parameter identifier and
declaration lists (not prototype-format parameter type and identifier
declarators) is an obsolescent feature.` so I would stick to `int
main(void)` for consistency.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't referring to the parameters with my quote above, just the return type. Personally I prefer `int main ()` over `int main (void)`, both are well-defined and portable though.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I actually thought you talk about parameters.